# What is login token and user token in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users, logins

I came across these two SQL Server catalog views today: [sys.login_token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-login-token-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) and [sys.user_token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-user-token-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The document states that they:

> Returns one row for every server principal that is part of the login token.

and

> Returns one row for every database principal that is part of the user token in SQL Server.

But what is a login token and a user token? I can't find any related information in the documentation. Could anyone help to explain a bit? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "token" in Kerberos or OAuth contains a list of the identities or "claims" that apply to a user.  So by analogy these views were added to list the server principals (logins, windows groups, etc), and database principals (users, roles, etc) that apply to the current user's session.